# Como enviar formulario al darle enter sin necesidad de boton?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

tengo este form en el que estoy añadiendo una forma de poder comentar, pero con el botón queda un poco raro en la sección de comentarios y me gustaría que añadiese los comentarios al darle enter. Tengo este html:

```
<form  role="form">
  <input id="comment" autocomplete="off" maxlength="60" placeholder="Say something nice..">
  <input id="user" type="hidden" value="prueba">
  <input id="photo" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['idPhoto']?>">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button id="submitComment" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
  </span>                          
</form>
```

Cuento con un ajax que es el que me captura los datos:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitComment").click(function() {
        var user = $("#user").val();
        var photo = $("#photo").val();
        var comment = $("#comment").val();
        // var now = new Date();
       
 
        var dataString = 'user=' + user + '&comment=' + comment + '&photo=' + photo;
        console.log(dataString);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "comentaris.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(response) {
              console.log(response);
              if (response) {
                document.getElementById("comment").value = "";
                $("#gallery-com").append(response.uno);
              }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Solo tienes que escuchar el evento submit del formulario, en vez del evento click del botón. Agregale un id al formulario, lo capturas en jquery, y aplicas la misma lógica siempre escuchando el submit del formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Agrega un id al form y un input de `type submit`.

Posteriormente en lugar de escuchar el click en `#submitComment` mandas directamente el submit al id del form.

Answer (score 0):

En el form deberías de crear el button o un input type=submit y en el script algo como esto
$("#formulario").submit(function(){
Lo quede ejecutara con el evento

```
});
```

Prueba esto y me dices